# No scheduled tasks in Esxi 5?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm using the free version of VMWare's ESXi 5.1.0.

I'm logged in as root in the vSphere client, and I want to create some scheduled tasks. According to the documentation, I should go to "Home"=>"Management"=>"Scheduled tasks".

However, when I go to "Home", I only have "Inventory" and "Administration". There is no "Management" section.

Is this a limitation of the free version (I doubt it, but still), or am I missing the obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.dcadmin.doc_41/vc_client_help/working_with_tasks/t_create_scheduled_tasks.html) confirms that you cannot define scheduled tasks on an ESXi alone.

You have to use vCenter.

However, you can create scheduled tasks directly on the ESXi host using SSH and the ESX's crontab: [here is an interesting Serverfault solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/240123/scheduling-vmware-esxi-4-1-vm-restart)

Comment: Thanks. Seems I didn't read manual well enough :-)